# ArrayAdapter building an ArrayList not handling click event correctly

Tags: java, android, callback, android-arrayadapter

I basically have 1 activity launch another one and build an ArrayList to populate the new activity.  I am trying to handle the list click event and pass back the picture or text name that was clicked in from the list.
This is my ArrayAdapter:

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    StatesHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new StatesHolder();
        holder.statePic = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgStatePic);
        holder.stateName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtStateName);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (StatesHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    States states = data.get(position);
    holder.stateName.setText(states.StateName);
    holder.statePic.setImageBitmap(states.StatePic);

    row.setClickable(true);
    row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityLocalReps.class);
            //intent.putExtras("StateName",  holder.stateName);  ** holder.stateName is not accessible here, I somehow need this info though.
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return row;
}
```

It would be great if I could pass something back in this call:

> Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityLocalReps.class(goodStuffINeed));

The activity I'm trying to call back is the exact previous activity that launched this new one.  I need to somehow overload the new Activity constructor with the click items info to flow differently through the original class, or to figure out what actual picture/value or text/value was clicked on.  That class:

```
boolean userSelectedCustomState = false;
String userSelectedState = "";
public ActivityLocalReps(String state){
    userSelectedCustomState = true;
    userSelectedState = state;
}
public ActivityLocalReps(){
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_local_reps);

    String imageName;
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras == null) {
            imageName = null;
        } else {
            imageName = extras.getString("StateName");
        }
    } else {
        imageName = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("StateName");
    }
```

I think I'm missing something here or don't have something setup right to handle this click action in the final class?  Thanks for the help!
**Edit 1:

```
 public void setStatesAdapter(ArrayList<States> allStates) {
    ChangeStateAdapter adapter = new ChangeStateAdapter(this, R.layout.list_states, allStates);
    ListView statesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_States);

    statesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityLocalReps.class);
            intent.putExtras("StateName", data.get(position).stateName);
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    statesListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Currently this line is not avialble and seems to be the piece I need to get:

> intent.putExtras("StateName", data.get(position).stateName);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an `OnClickListener`, use `OnItemClickListener`. It works better for `Adapters`. E.g.:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityLocalReps.class);
        intent.putExtras("StateName", data.get(position).stateName);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

You should avoid trying working with `ViewHolder`s (`StatesHolder`, in your case) or the rows of an adapter directly. Work instead with the data backing the views. It's a better pattern.

**EDIT** You're correct, you can't call this code inside your `getView()` method. It needs to be up where you create your adapter and set it on the listview (as you have shown in your edit). To answer your question about how to get the data, you can call the following method of the [`Adapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem(int)) class (which you should override):

```
@Override
public States getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}
```

Make sure you also override [`getCount()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getCount())

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}
```

Your adapter won't work properly unless you do.

Comment: There is no "setOnItemClickListener" within a getView override of an extended ArrayAdapter class it seems.  So, if I move your above code to class calling the adapater as you suggested, I have an issue with the data.get(position).stateName line.  See above edit 1 please.